# Simperium unshare API for HTTP

Tags: ios, api, http, share, simperium

According to the Simperium HTTP reference, there is an API for sharing an object in a bucket with another username by supplying the email.

Is there any way for the owner to unshare a previously shared item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently - the closest would be to re-create the item under a different id, then delete the original shared one.